# There must be an uncomplex way to copy elements of struct to an array, and vice versa

Tags: c, embedded

1. At startup, I want to save `uint8_t` array values to the struct with `uint16_t` elements with  `memcpy`function inside `Counter_Read(void)`  function. Although `memcpy` function works but it gives me little-endian values. so I create the `uint16_t` array from `uint8_t` array and then use the `memcpy` function works fine but is there a better way of doing this?
2. At shutdown, I want to save `uint16_t` elements of the struct to an `uint8_t` array. I am trying to use the pointer here but it doesn't increment the address of the element!.. do we normally swap the array elements or is there a better way of doing this?

here is my code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t EssEvRPM;                  
    uint16_t Essev_TrqLd;               
    uint16_t Essev_Reku;                
    uint16_t Essev_NormProp;            

} S_Counter_t;
S_Counter_t Counter =
{
    .EssEvRPM               = 0x0000U,
    .Essev_TrqLd            = 0x0000U,
    .Essev_Reku             = 0x0000U,
    .Essev_NormProp         = 0x0000U,
};
const S_Counter_t* GetCounterConstPtr(void)
{
    return &Counter;
}

void Counter_Read(void)
{
    S_Counter_t* pCounter = GetCounterConstPtr();
    // We get uint8_t from MEMnv area
    uint8_t SigData[sizeof(S_Counter_t)]={0x1F,0x2F,0x3F,0x4F,0x5F,0x6F,0x7F,0x8F};
    uint16_t aCounter[sizeof(S_Counter_t)/2];
    
    // read at startup,
    // read uint8_t array and save to uint16_t array
    int j=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(aCounter); i++) {
        aCounter[i] = (uint16_t)(SigData[j] << 8)| SigData[++j];
      j++;
    }
    
    // assign array values to struct: S_Counter_t
    memcpy(pCounter, aCounter, sizeof(aCounter));
    
    // printf("\n-> %x %x %x %x",pCounter->EssEvRPM,pCounter->Essev_TrqLd,pCounter->Essev_Reku,pCounter->Essev_NormProp);// -> 1f2f 3f4f 5f6f 7f8f
}

void Counter_Write(void)
{
    S_Counter_t* pCounter = GetCounterConstPtr();
    uint8_t aCounterBuffer[sizeof(S_Counter_t)];
    // returns us "2f 1f 4f 3f 6f 5f 8f 7f" but we want 1f 2f 3f 4f 5f
    memcpy(aCounterBuffer, pCounter, sizeof(aCounterBuffer)); //
    
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(aCounterBuffer);i++)
    {
        aCounterBuffer[i] = *((uint8_t*)&(*pCounter)+1); //high byte
        aCounterBuffer[i+1] = *((uint8_t*)&(*pCounter)+0); //low byte
        *pCounter++; // doesn't work
    }
    // we save uint8_t aCounterBuffer to MEMnv area
}

int main()
{
    Counter_Read();
    Counter_Write();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use an `union`?

Comment: You can use `union` to do your desired.

Comment: `union` may be used in this case or `memcpy` in general.

Comment: It seems to me that `Counter_Read` fills a struct with constant values - correct? If so, why don't you just assign the values?

Comment: BTW: Do you know about these functions: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htons.3.html

Comment: I am not using union because with struct I can access individual members and I can initialize different members at once. The `Counter_Read` doesn't fill the struct with constant values, for this example, I have provided some constant values

Comment: Using `memcpy` is like "playing with fire". struct may have padding - read about packed structs

Comment: Why don't you simply do: `p->EssEvRPM = (uint16_t)(SigData[0] << 8) | SigData[1];` ? It's 4 simple lines.

Comment: And similar for the write: `aCounterBuffer[0] = p->EssEvRPM >> 8; aCounterBuffer[1] = p->EssEvRPM  & 0xff;` It's 8 simple lines.

Comment: all member elements of the struct are of the same type `uint16_t` and they are exactly 60Bytes so maybe we are talking about 4 instruction cycles here. But with padding, I am not sure if we need to do anything here

Comment: I have 30 elements in my struct, is `p->EssEvRPM = (uint16_t)(SigData[0] << 8) | SigData[1];` it a really better way of doing it, we are talking about 60lines here?

Comment: @OmChoudhary The shifting is in general better. You don't get in to trouble with endianess and struct padding. Doing `memcpy` between an array and a struct is like opening a can of worms. If you have a lot of members you can go for a union but remember to use a packed struct... and take care of system endianess

Comment: Why do you not actually store the data in NvM the same way, as you read it? That you get uint8_t array out is just due to the byte.wise storage, but when your have an `uint16_t Value = 0x1234u, NvValue = 0;  NvM_WriteBlock(BlockId, &Value);` and then read the bloock back with `NvM_ReadBlock(BlockId, &NvValue);`.

Comment: Why is it a problem to get little endian values if your CPU is little endian? Why can't you simply use that format all over?